# hdfs file is not distributed

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and I'm going to configure the hadoop cluster. The Version of Hadoop is 3.1.3. I want to set the NameNode, DataNode, NodeManager on host hadoop102, DataNode, ResourceNode, NodeManager on host hadoop103, and SecondaryNameNode, DataNode, NodeManager on hadoop104

core-site.xml

```
<configuration> 
    <property> 
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name> 
        <value>hdfs://hadoop102:8020</value> 
    </property> 
    <property> 
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
        <value>/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/data</value> 
    </property> 

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration> 
  <property> 
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name> 
        <value>hadoop102:9870</value> 
    </property> 
    <property> 
        <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name> 
        <value>hadoop104:9868</value> 
    </property> 
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration> 
    <property> 
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name> 
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> 
    </property> 
 
    <property> 
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name> 
        <value>hadoop103</value> 
    </property> 

    <property> 
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name> 
        
<value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value> 
    </property> 
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration> 
    <property> 
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> 
        <value>yarn</value> 
    </property> 
</configuration>
```

workers

```
hadoop102
hadoop103
hadoop104
```

I upload the test file from host hadoop102 with the command

`hadoop fs -put $HADOOP_HOME/wcinput/word.txt /input`

Why the file is only available on hadoop102? I think the file should be copied into hadoop103, hadoop104 in the local file system.

[File Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMkk2.png)

Comment: What did you set the replication factor to?  Did you get an error message? what's the output of [ hdfs fsck / -files -blocks -racks ]

Comment: The file should not be copied in the **local** filesystem. The HDFS replication defaults to only 1. Also, I suggest Apache Ambari for properly setting up a distributed, configured Hadoop cluster

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that HDFS is not like replicated file system, so if you put one file to HDFS does not mean that it will be placed on data nodes as files (under / filesystem for example).

HDFS splits the file into blocks, and these blocks are replicated on your cluster and configured by replication factor.
When you run -copyFromLocal or hdfs put what does perform is just split the file into blocks and send these blocks in replicated fashion.

So if one node goes down. you can still retrieve your file.

But where's my file? the file will not be in your machines' local filesystem. It will be stored on data nodes.

How can you configure the number of replicas?
You can setup dfs.replication to 3 in hdfs-site.xml

and you set number of replica for a file:

> hadoop fs –setrep –w 3 /my/file

You can change the replication factor of all the files under a directory.

> hadoop fs –setrep –w 3 -R /my/dir